# How to make the AI Chase in Multiplayer

Tags: c#, java, libgdx, ai

Im Currently develop a little Dungeon Crawler. The Singeplayer works fine, but it also should have multiplayer so i implemented it. But there's one problem. I have no idea how to make the AI chase the player and the other players. In singleplayer it works like this :

```
if(distanceToPlayer <= 400f){

   entity.chase(playerEntity);

}
```

Heres my full chasing code :

// in enemy update method i put all multiplayers into a map with their login number..

```
 // Pick a random Multiplayer and chase him

        boolean isAvaible = false;

 //Convert Map to Object array
        Object[] values = ((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.values().toArray();

        int rdm = 0;

        float randomValue = 0;

        // wenn map isnt empty
        if(((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.size() > 0){

            rdm = generator.nextInt(values.length);

            randomValue = (float)values[rdm];

            isAvaible = true;

        }

        //selecting the key     
        // +2 because the first joined player is the second Player in the game so it begins with connection 2, the second with 3 and so on.
        int key = rdm + 2;

        // Only printing stuff
        System.out.println("Found a Map : "+((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos + "Size of da HashMap : "+ ((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.size());
        System.out.println("Found a Random Value : "+rdm + " "+randomValue );
        System.out.println("Found a Key: "+key + " "+((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.get(key) );

        // When the multiplayer is near the enemy than
        if (/*((EnemyEntity)arg0).distanceToNextPlayer < 400 && arg0.isAlive() == true */ isAvaible && ((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.get(rdm) != null && ((EnemyEntity)arg0).mpSortedPos.get(rdm) < 400) {

            ((EnemyEntity)arg0).activated = true; 

            arg0.stateMachine.changeState(CHASE_ENTITY);

        }
```

This is my code for multiplayer chasing but it doesnt work ... any ideas ? What could i improve ?

But how should i do that with multiple players ? Any ideas ? :)

Comment: How much do you know about route finding algorithms like A* or Dijkstra's algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the same way. You just have to pick an algorithm to select a player to chase from available players. E.g. by factoring distance to the player, remaining hitpoints, random, etc.

Comment: That sounds logical, updated my question, maybe you could add some simple code or help me to solve mine ? :/